# Problem when run adb command / Problem of developing with tablet device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I followed the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) to set up [ZTE tablet](http://www.okepos.com/zte-light-pro-android-tablet-review-price-specifications.html) device for development. I am developing under Ubuntu 10.04.

After create the rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="19D2", MODE="0666"
```

After I plug in the ZTE tablet device with debugging enabled. I run command:

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server

adb devices
```

I got :

```
List of devices attached 

????????????    no permissions
```

I thought may be it is because I did not restart adb as root. SO, I tried to restart adb as root, and I entered the command in my terminal:

**sudo adb kill-server** , but I got the message in terminal that "**sudo: adb: command not found**"

But if I enter command without "sudo", that's "adb kill-server" it works.

Is it because my path setting is wrong?????

I set the **path** under ***HOME/.bashrc***, with :

```
export PATH=$PATH{}:/home/user/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools:/home/user/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools
```

Conclude all above, I got two problems:

1. the adb listed device has **no permissions**
2. I can not run adb as root

My questions:

1. Are the problems all because of my path setting is wrong?
2. Is it because ZTE tablet device is different from mobile device? Some tricks need to be done for tablet??
3. something else?

Where am I wrong?

P.S. Since I lost the USB cable shipped with the ZTE tablet, I use a NOKIA USB cable to connect the ZTE tablet with my development Ubuntu machine, could this also cause the above problems???? (With Nokia USB cable, I can still access the ZTE tablet file system anyhow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every thing goes fine after I run the command:

```
sudo -s
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

Then my ZTE tablet is shown.

Comment: I met your problem, and your way works fine. But do you know how to use "sudo adb", I dit it in the past but now I can't find the guide which I followed